# Net Reflector decompile issue - wrong method names etc

Tags: c#, decompiling, reflector

Hello i try to restore 1 of my old app's source code, 
i tried to do it via NetReflector 8.1,

but when i use it all the method / vars names are weird and incorrect

for example:

```
   this.NvbptLvr7r.Text = this.BvTcVeQN3(kaynak, nMPB2IkG5eDU0xeMxh.bmn4lTe8G(0x42e0));
   this.CSDp2D34j2.Text = this.BvTcVeQN3(kaynak, nMPB2IkG5eDU0xeMxh.bmn4lTe8G(0x42f2));
   this.c0CpFuprih.Text = this.BvTcVeQN3(kaynak, nMPB2IkG5eDU0xeMxh.bmn4lTe8G(0x4304));
```

or

```
namespace h23ciRHHe5guvO7A9D
{
    internal class Cqlh4hG00c9E7mhrh7
    {
        // Fields
        public List<5pfK6QIGkyFTUpujuA> gOKvP6hjp;
        public Timer xUsNoDreR;
        private 2saEgVZw9XGlQyUr6y xYWUGpMKO;
```

anyone have any idea why it is happening? and how i can solve it?

Comment: Sounds like your class name and fields were obfuscated, you can do a find replace where you know what they are though.

Comment: New product idea: .NET Reflactor.  (See original post).

Comment: If that version of Reflector gives you that output, it's likely right. You had your code previously obfuscated with another software (maybe Xenocode?).

Comment: What happened to your original source code?

Answer (score 2):

The code has been obfuscated, you can do a find replace on methods and classes which you know the name of. Outside of that you really have to my knowledge no other options, so this is why backups and offsite storage are critical.